# Suggested design patterns or basic use case of reflection?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, system.reflection

I know some of relection capabilities, but i never understand exectly when and why should i use them , I would like some examples on how and when is a good idea to use it? 
What are the design patterns you know wich performed with reflection?
Is there any operation that can be done only with the use of reflection?

Comment: I like to override `.ToString()` to enumerate the name/values of all properties on an object. It helps debugging.

Answer (score 1):

very common use case: calling a function decided at run time.

Imagine a server that accepts requests like this

```
foo(3)
bar("joe")
wiz(42.0)
```

You need to write code that looks up to find the requested method and call it. You could do that with a big switch statement but that doesnt work in some cases (maybe you allow dlls to be loaded at different time that has different functions), also you need to work out what transformations need to be made of the paramters.

Instead you do

```
  // name = method to execute
  // module is instance of execution code class
  var method = module.GetType().GetMethod(name, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
  method.Invoke(module, ....);
```

Comment: Wow , didn't know it is a very powerfull operation.

Comment: BTW this is better solved with a dictionary where key is the method name and the method itself is a delegate...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer  in many cases it is not, for example a dynamically loaded dll that has unknown functions in it. I agree for a fixed set of functions this is not the best solution

Comment: I would mention that in your answer, because your example of dynamically loaded assemblies that has unknown functions in them may be a corner case :\

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is a powerful tool to implement *difuse* programming. When you know what you want, but you don't know what you'll get until run-time, reflection is the answer.

Common scenarios:

#### 1) Meta-programming: Attributes.

When you need to extend the language to provide more meaning where access modifiers (`public`, `private`...) aren't enough, you use *attributes*.

Attributes are associated with assembly members and type members, and they need to be got using reflection.

Given the following attribute and a class using the whole attribute:

```
public class NameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public NameAttribute(string name) 
    {
         Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}

[Name("Custom name")]
public class A
{

}
```

...you get the attribute using reflection:

```
NameAttribute nameAttr = typeof(A).GetCustomAttribute<NameAttribute>();
```

Since attributes are regular classes, they provide a powerful way of associating metadata to assemblies, classes, interfaces, enumerations and type members during compile-time to get them during run-time based on a set of conditions.

#### 2) To implement *convention over configuration*

*Convention over configuration* is a powerful development paradigm to implement frameworks and libraries that work with near to zero configuration and, if you follow some rules, they get automatically configured.

Reflection plays an important role here. For example, Entity Framework can determine which is the *primary key* on the database when using Code First strategy using reflection.

Given an entity like the following one:

```
public class Customer
{
     public Guid Id { get; set }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

...Entity Framework may know that `Id` will be the *primary key* by convention, and using reflection can find out if there's an `Id` property:

```
PropertyInfo idProperty = typeof(Customer).GetProperty("Id", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

if(idProperty != null) 
{
    // Yes, it has an Id property!
}
```

#### 3) To take decisions during run-time

Since reflection enables your code to introspect and execute nearly everything you could do during compile-time (obviously, with a high performance impact), it lets you get a method, property or whatever based on a search and invoke them to get or set values.

#### 4) Expression trees: introspecting expression's body

Expression trees are a powerful tool in C# to produce code as a *data structure*.

For example, I can define a class `FileChecker` and wrap a call to its `Exists` method in an expression tree, and later get which method was called, its parameters and even the class which declares the whole method during run-time using reflection:

```
public class FileChecker
{
     public bool Exists(string filePath) { }
}

Checker checker = new Checker();
Expression<Func<bool>> expr = () => checker.Exists(@"C:\hello.txt");

MethodCallExpression methodCallExpr = (MethodCallExpression)expr.Body;

MethodInfo calledMethod = methodCallExpr.Method;
IEnumerable<ParameterInfo> inputParams = calledMethod.GetParameters();
Type declaringType = calledMethod.DeclaringType;
```